# Update questions to improve tags

Tags: discussion, tags, ethics

I'm wondering a question: is there a **time slot** to improve and update many question with a new tag?

During twenty minutes, I updated questions (as revelant category) which refer all the questions with parent and child fragments in Android with the new tag [android-nested-fragment](/questions/tagged/android-nested-fragment).

However I stopped when I thought about the active page, there is obviously a lot of questions updated:

[image]

<sup>Seven updated questions versus one new question... *Glup!*</sup>
Is there a time slot, an hour, when the number of current and active SO users are lower to improve, edit and update many question?

Comment: Based from my observation: when people on the Atlantic side are sleeping (around 2 AM GMT). But that's just my opinion, since SO is global anyway. I assume you asked this because you want to reduce annoyance for people who are watching "Active" tabs?

Comment: There is a post [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/what-is-the-best-time-to-ask-questions)

Comment: On a side-note: If you edit a question to add a tag, please fix everything. Some posts you touched had for me some obvious grammar errros and taglines left that could have been fixed in the same edit.

Comment: @rene Yes, it's true. I didn't edit the context but only the tag. I will change that too. And I think, the number of questions in *active page* will be reduce.

Comment: Perfect related post, Thanks @rene! However, did the stats change a lot since 2009?

Comment: I don't know. I have seen a more recent one but I can't find it now.

Comment: @AndrewT. Exactly, it might be frustrating to see the same guy updates many question over and over.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207330/what-to-do-about-mass-edits-of-old-questions and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109510/tool-for-peer-reviewed-no-bump-mass-retagging.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @ShadowWizard. I didn't find these posts. I'll read carefully.

Comment: @Fllo well, they're in a different site now so you couldn't find them here. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to go about this is pretty much what you've done. There seems to be a gathering consensus that the addition of the tags is important, and something that people care about. Given that, don't worry *too* much about 'churn' on Stack Overflow - even at our lowest activity peaks questions don't stay on the front page nearly as long as they do on other sites.

That said, there's a bit of a lull around 8-ish PM Eastern until Asia really starts kicking in, but we're still talking a great deal of scale, there's no real time that activity hits a *major* lull with the exception of major holidays.

Just post what you're doing here, and if anyone asks, give them the link. If the edits are good, the churn is more than worth it.

Comment: I actually finish to read the shared links from @ShadowWizard and the first was my acts, the second the supected *and indeed* behaviour on the site (flood, overflow the frontpage, even if questions don't stay as long as other sites) also maybe the solution (retag with a community tool). I think the simplest and right solution for me will be: to keep the questions which don't need too much correction and edit them when the number of users is a bit lower, **and** to edit carefully the others (grammar, typo, content) and retag it in small batches - until the community tool is created.

Comment: Tim, isn't this question better fitting in MSE? I think it's a general discussion about mass retagging by high rep non mod user and how it affects the front page, so it might as well apply for all sites. What do you think?